# How to load iframe instantly with javascript?

Tags: javascript

There are so much Q/A but none of them are solving my problem for my iframe which is showing sometimes only or after doing a clean refresh.

I've tried the following and others too but no luck to work:

```
document.getElementById('Reloader').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

As my frame is loading from outside the domain so above code won't work.

```
<iframe id="Reloader" src="http://www.domain.com/somthing" style="width:700px; height: 400px; overflow:hidden;border: 0px solid #fff;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

What's the way I can do?

Comment: Try to "change" the `src` of the `iframe` instead.

Comment: @Teemu not working in chrome 32....

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('Reloader').src = document.getElementById('Reloader').src
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/836hj/)

If you want to break a cache,

```
var src = document.getElementById('Reloader').src;
var param = '_=' + +new Time;
if(src.indexOf('_=') >= 0) {            // already broke cache
    src = src.replace(/_=\d+/, param);
} else if(src.indexOf('?') >= 0) {      // no query params
    src += '&' + param;
} else {                                // existing query params
    src += '?' + param;
}
document.getElementById('Reloader').src = src;
```

Comment: I've tried that too but not working... works sometimes only. I think cache problem?

Comment: don't know about that?

Comment: @C-link, http://jsfiddle.net/836hj/ works for me. Could you perhaps give the URL of the iframe that isn't working for you?

Comment: Sorry, I won't accept your answer but +1 that you tried, I've just solved my problem, check my answer. And thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

There is embed element inside of iframe and iframe. Now just copied that embed element into html and removed iframe element which now loading and working perfectly.